# How to check if a phone can be rooted? Can the Fujitsu Arrows 201F be rooted?

Tags: rooting, root-access

I want to have a phone that I can root.  Today, I'm trying to purchase one.  I want to know if my phone can be rooted in advance.  The selections of phones from my provider, Softbank, is limited and the phones are all outdated.  But I have a discount, so I want to get one of them.  The Arrows 201F is the phone with the best battery life, so I want to get that one.  But first, I want to know if it can be rooted?  Can it?  And if not, how do I check the other phones at Softbank to see if they can be rooted?

Comment: You could check our [rooting index](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184/16575) to see if it's listed, and has a rooting solution mentioned. Searching the web, especially [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/) is another good approach. No guarantees, however, for any results :)

Comment: @Izzy Good comment, man.  I threw up a post for the 201 and 301 on XDA.  They're looking into it.  I've found I need to learn some basic stuff about rooting phones.  For example, can roms for one phone be used on another?  Can sudo-access programs be run on similarly-modeled phones.  Of course, I had already checked the index prior to asking.  Naturally, the phone I've mentioned isn't listed.

Comment: @Izzy Read this post: it's an offshoot of the link you gave me: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2239958.  The guy says: 'Just try it!  If it doesn't work, shoot me an image of the issue!  Hand me a PM!'

Comment: We have plenty questions on those topics as well. Recommendation: Check the corresponding tag-wikis and frequent questions, e.g. on [rom](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rom/info) (short answer: ROMs are device-specific due to hardware and driver issues). *Superuser* and *SuperSU* on the other hand are not device specific. // And yes, there are several rather generic rooting methods, also listed in our rooting index :)

Comment: @Izzy You know, man: I don't even know if I want to root it.  I just want to be able to run stuff as a sudo user.  Like, I want to be able to read and write in memory, for example.  And I want to be able to programmatically turn on GPS....

Comment: Just another hint: [chat is over here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25/android), not in the comments :) You have the required rep, so feel welcome.

Comment: @Izzy This comes up as the top google result for "can my phone be rooted" or "how can I check if my phone can be rooted".  Obvious keywords, you know?  I think the phrasing is important: gives people a GENERAL resource for understanding whether or not any given phone can be rooted, and how to figure out if it can or cannot be rooted, alone.  I tried to root my prior phone, found out two years later that it could have been rooted the whole time--, but I was told it couldn't be.